# How to differentiate PHP Session across different accessing domains

Tags: php

I am using a single php file, and that is included in many other websites using iframe, when two websites accessing same file via iframe, the session is not differentiated and php uses same session variable for different referring domains.

I want to restrict session referal domain wise.

Comment: Same user calling same page will get the same session... but that doesn't matter. Just show independent results based on location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?
Quoting: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
'REMOTE_ADDR'
  The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.
```

Comment: U prolly meant `SERVER_ADDR` instead of `REMOTE_ADDR` as `REMOTE_ADDR` returns the clients IP address

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing that 2 websites on one machine & one browser, there is no differences, Just like one person open a web page in 2 browser tabs => same session.
In 2 browsers, ofcourse they will be diffrent.

If you want different sessions in that case. Create session by your self, depends on referrer domain (parent page domain) / User Agent and User IP to create user session. Do everything else base on that session (Ignore default one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, which contains the current domain name the user uses.